# Program to detect registry keys

Tags: windows, registry, detection

I’m trying to find an application that can detect what windows registry keys are being accessed by a second application.

Let me try to explain a little better: I'm looking for a program A that I can point to a program B and when I run program B, program A will tell me all the registry keys accessed by program B. Does such program exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) from SysInternals does that exactly, along with filesystem access and much more.